# Vmware fusions with VM's on network share

Tags: vmware-fusion

I am running Vmware Fusions with 3 virtual machines on my current 2010 13 macbook pro 8 gb ram. As of late my VMs has become kind of unruly and sluggish. I do run them at the same time I have been running them and suspending them as to not take performance hit. 
Is it possible to run the vm from an external location like a network share? Or is a portable external drive the better solution? I don't necessarily need to be mobile with my machine. I do need some increased performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly won't get extra performance by running VMs over a network share.  Your sluggish performance is likely due to your computer using swap, as you are likely out of RAM.

Even after you pause a VM, you will find that it still consumes a ton of memory.  VMWare cleans up stuff in the background even after it appears "paused", and the memory won't be freed for several minutes.

In some cases, I have had to reboot to clear up memory, due a bug in older versions of VMWare Desktop.